# Static deployment errors Magento 2.2

Tags: error, deploy, static-content-deploy

> Hi everyone I am having an issue after installing a theme.
>
> when I run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy I get:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes.
In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed automatically on demand.
If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option: 'bin/magento setup:static-content: deploy -f'
```

> If I force deploy with

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

> I get the following errors:

```
Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2005/2124           
==========================>- 94% %   15 secs
#0 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#2 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#3 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(185): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('css/newletterpo...', Array)
#4 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(132): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#5 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(103): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service\{closure}()
#7 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(186): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(104): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure))
#9 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(281): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deploy(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array)
#10 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(200): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->execute(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#11 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(162): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->assertAndExecute('frontend/Magent...', Array, Array)
#12 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Strategy/QuickDeploy.php(76): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->process()
#13 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticContent.php(109): Magento\Deploy\Strategy\QuickDeploy->deploy(Array)
#14 /home/rbadmin/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(140): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent->deploy(Array)
#15 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(266): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(875): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(204): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(104): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /home/rbadmin/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(122): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /home/rbadmin/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2028/2124           ==========================>- 95% %   21 secs


 [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
 Cannot read contents from file "/home/rbadmin/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Plazathemes_Newsletterpopup/css/newletterpopup.css" Warning!file_get_contents(/home/rbadmin/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Plazathemes_Newsletterpopup/css/newletterpopup.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What mode are you running ? if it is developer mode you don't need to deploy the static content, its symlinked

Comment: not sure, to be honest, I am just following a theme install instructions which says to run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy, like I did for 2.1.8 and 2.1.9 and didn't have these issues?

Comment: hi, I am facing similar issues in deployment .Can you share the solution if have solved this..thanks in advance

Comment: @andyjones: I've just faced the problem that when synlinks are created, they have ownership `www-data:www-data`, while the content the link to is `www-data:www-data`. This results ` AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible` error if `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` not set in e.g. `.htaccess`. If that option is unset, then product images are not shown due to `AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMa
tch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions : .../pub/media/catalog/...`.